# How do I animate a sprite using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite which will move right,left and jump.
I need to add the action to a animated sprite ie an animated sprite should jump, turn right and left.
Can anyone please tell me how to do it with sample code.

Comment: What language?  What graphics library?  What platform?  How are you storing sprites?  How do you want to animate them?

Comment: I am using Cocos2d for iphone.
i am using a normal sprite with png format.
I will use a for loop to play the animation.
But how to move the animation when it is playing.
Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite simple with cocos2d code here:

```
Sprite *mySprite = [Sprite spriteWithFile@"mySprite.png"];
[mySprite setPosition:ccp(x,y)];
[self addChild:mySprite]; //This displays the Sprite in your layer
```

Now for the sequence you intend to do...

```
id moveRight = [MoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position ccp(x+k,y) //Where k is how much to the right you want it to go.
id moveLeft = [MoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position ccp(x-k,y)];
id jump = [JumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp (x,y) height:1 jumps:1];
id sequence = [Sequence actions:moveRight,moveLeft,jump,nil];
[mySprite runAction:sequence];
```

Hope that's clear.

-Oscar